# Can't add images to login page

Tags: html, asp.net, css, webforms

First, the code of the login.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="DoubleEntryForm.Account.Login" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    &nbsp;Log In
</h2>
<%--<p>
    Please enter your username and password.
    <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink> if you don't have an account.
</p>--%>
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false" DestinationPageUrl="~/Destruction Form.aspx">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <span class="failureNotification">
            <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </span>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="LoginUserValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification" 
             ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="login">
                <legend>Account Information</legend>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" CssClass="passwordEntry" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" 
                         CssClass="failureNotification" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." 
                         ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server"/>
                    <asp:Label ID="RememberMeLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="RememberMe" CssClass="inline">Keep me logged in</asp:Label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <p class="submitButton">
                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="LoginUserValidationGroup"/>
            </p>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

On this page, I'm trying to add some CSS styling, and every way I'm trying is not working. Here's that styling:

```
<style type="text/css">

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#eae9e9;}

#scan-table-wrapper {
    width: 968px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-image: url("Images/wrapper-bg.png");}    

#scan-table-body{
    margin:0 30px 0 30px;
    padding-top:30px;}

.auto-style1 {
    width: 880px;
    height: 100px;}

</style>
```

I'm also trying to add a title image as well. However, if I put the code in the HeaderContent section, it looks like it tries to show the title image and fails, and doesn't show the background at all (by failing, i mean an empty box shows up with a small red X in it). If I put it in MainContent, it states that I can't put style in a div. However, I'm not putting it in a div, but I'm putting it in the line right below where MainContent starts.

This is my first time heavily dealing with CSS, so I'm a bit unfamiliar. Where should I put these so that they'll properly show on my page?

Comment: It's very important to remember where your stylesheet lives in relation to your images folder, otherwise the image paths could be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your  tag will go into the HeadContent , content. If your are seeing a image with red cross that means the css is working fine but is unable to find the image in the  directory you have mentioned. Kindly set the appropriate path using `../` which means one directory up.

For example if your project structure is this

```
Root -> Images/wrapper-bg.png
     -> Pages/Your Aspx pages
```

and in your aspx page you have your style then you have to use

### background-image: url('../Images/wrapper-bg.png');} // use single quote

../ will move you outside the pages directory and place you inside the root, in case of above and then the Images/Wrapper-bg.png and the path will get satisfied. Thats all.

### For Body Bg

Move your css to Head section of master page. Be sure there must be no more css for body is applied either from external css or inline css.

### A good way to deal with CSS

Add a Stylesheet in your project name it style.css or whatever you like. Drag drop the css file to your master page head section, it will automatically add its reference. Now start writing your css in that file. All child pages will automatically inherit the style from that file based on your instructions. Also you can use some third party CSS Editor for easy writing css and learning too. I generally use [Rapid CSS](http://www.blumentals.net/rapidcss/).

### Must give a try

My very preferred mode is .Net itself with Jetbrains Resharper. Thats really cool!!

Comment: even after trying that, i'm still not getting the background image or title image. The CSS is applying properly to the page, as it's changed the background color. It's just not applying the images properly.

Comment: @MichaelBowman can write down your project directory structure

Comment: Root -> Account -> ASPX files
Root -> Images folder -> image files

Comment: didn't work. to be honest, it's not a pivotal feature, and through troubleshooting i believe it's because of the master site's formatting. i don't really care to continue with this any longer. however, thank you very much for your assitance.